# Auto-Indent in Pycharm to Take Into Account Jinja Conditionals in Templates

Tags: pycharm, jinja2

What is the simplest way to make PyCharm to take into account Jinja control expressions when auto-indenting?

I want to increase the indent of the code inside a conditional like this:

```
{% if is_teacher %}
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('account.students') }}">My Students</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
{% endif %}
```

Instead of the default:

```
{% if is_teacher %}
<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="{{ url_for('account.cohorts') }}">My Students</a></li>
<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Found it! Indentation for Jinja2 templates can be enabled via the not-very-intuitive named preference page `Languages & Frameworks > Python Template Language`:

[image]

Comment: tried it. didn't work. still does not ident jinja conditionals